# Plotted LDA Analysis in R - how to drawn attention to/reclassify outliers?

Tags: r, lda, outliers

I have some clinical data that I ran an LDA analysis on - 98 patients and their corresponding protein levels for a specific type of analysis.  I plotted the output and have essentially 6 different "clusters" of individuals.  Here's the problem - some of the clusters have outliers that are much closer to other clusters.  We know that in some cases the medical diagnosis that the cluster is based on (phenotype) might be in error, and the outlier member of the green cluster that appears closer to the blu cluster might actually *be* part of the blue cluster.  So my question is:  is there a computational way for me detect these individuals and re-evaluate whether or not they are actually members of the cluster they are closer to based on the data if we ignore the medical diagnosis?

Here's a sample of the output:
[image]